# Understanding classes: why is this attribute redefinition taken into account while this other one isn't?

Tags: python

I'm new to classes, and there is a behavior that I do not understand: why is the 6th line ignored in this example, while the 7th isn't?

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, name = "some default name", age = 999):
        self.username = name
        self.age = age

    username = "why isn't this line having any effect"
    city = "while this one does" 

user1 = User("john", 25)
print(user1.city)
print(user1.username)
```

I'd expect `john` to be overwritten by `why isn't this line having any effect`, and therefore to have the following output:

```
why isn't this line having any effect
while this one does
```

But here is the output that I get:

```
john
while this one does
```

PS: I do get that defining the default value for `city` this way means I can't set it to something else when instantiating the class and therefore why it's better to set the default value in `def __init__()`. I also get that what my code is trying to do to `username` would defeat the point of being able to instantiate with a different `username` each time. But both of these valid points are not the point.

PS2: I'm not quite sure how to name things yet and therefore what terms should go in the title, so please feel free to edit the title to something more useful for future users. Thanks.

Comment: Because `self.username` is *shadowing the class variable `User.username`*. It is best not to think of class variables as "default variables" unless you really understand what they are. Note, neither of those lines is "ignored", you can still see the value if oyu do `User.username`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two different `username` variables -- one is a class variable, one is an instance variable.  Try this to see both of them:

```
print((User.username, user1.username))
```

Since there is no `city` instance variable, `user1.city` defaults to `User.city`.